# Global functions on WPMU

Tags: functions, multisite, globals

I work in a multisite environment where all of the sites are related.  A lot of recent developments have required me to copy and paste certain functions into many different theme folders, which causes problems if I need to update them everywhere.

What would be the best way to have a global "functions.php" file?  My thoughts are either to include a file in the themes folder and include it, or create a plugin and network enable the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What you are looking for is a "MU-Plugin"-- "Must-Use Plugin".](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Originally these were called "Multi-User Plugins" and were intended for exactly your purpose-- to provide a way for site admins to enable functionality on all sites of an installation.

Create a directory at `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` and put your PHP file(s) in it. WordPress will load the files automatically. MU-PLugins are ["are automatically enabled on all sites in the installation"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and cannot be deactivated except by physically removing the file.

Be sure to read the ["Caveats"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins#Caveats) part of the Codex page.